# Does the Thunderwave spell push back a Cloud of Daggers?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, area-of-effect

If there is an active *Cloud of Daggers* spell within the AOE of a *Thunderwave* spell, would the *Cloud of Daggers* spell be pushed back 10 feet?

From the description of [*Thunderwave*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/thunderwave):

> In addition, unsecured objects that are completely within the area of effect are automatically pushed 10 feet away from you by the spell's effect, ...

Is a *Cloud Of Daggers* considered an unsecured object for the purpose of 
*Thunderwave*?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### No

*Cloud of Daggers* says:

> You fill the air with spinning daggers in a cube 5 feet on
>   each side, centered on a point you choose within range.
>   A creature takes 4d4 slashing damage when it enters
>   the spell’s area for the first time on a turn or starts
>   its turn there.

The thing that *Thuderwave* would need to move is the "point you choose within range" - this is not an object so cannot be moved.

Comment: This is certainly the easiest way to justify it, however spells can create objects. Can you explain a bit more (maybe using examples of the language spells use when they do) to support why you think this particular spells does not create objects?

Comment: I would think the spinning daggers are objects in the air but you could argue that the daggers are secured objects by "a point you choose".

Comment: As a flavor thing, you might allow the daggers themselves to be pushed away briefly, but the "**spell's area**" is based on the point you choose within range, so that's where the damaging effect takes place.